# Upload file to Azure blob using Java SDK

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-for-java

I'm trying to implement a piece of code in Java using Azure Java SDK that allows me to upload a file (jpg, in mycase) to a Azure container. I have written this, but it fails:

```
String ENDPOINT= "https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net";

BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = new BlobContainerClientBuilder().
    endpoint(ENDPOINT).
    credential(CREDENTIAL).
    containerName(CONTAINER_NAME).
    buildClient();

// Get a reference to a local image
BlobClient blobClient = blobContainerClient.getBlobClient(myJpgLocalPath + myJpgFile);

// Set headers
blobClient.setHttpHeaders(new BlobHttpHeaders().setContentType("image/jpeg"));

// Upload the blob
blobClient.uploadFromFile(myJpgLocalPath + myJpgFile, false);
```

Another approach I've done is this:

```
BlobServiceClient storageClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().
    endpoint(ENDPOINT).
    credential(CREDENTIAL).
    buildClient();

BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = storageClient.getBlobContainerClient(CONTAINER_NAME); 

// Get a reference to a local image
BlobClient blobClient = blobContainerClient.getBlobClient(myJpgLocalPath + myJpgFile);
    
// Set headers
blobClient.setHttpHeaders(new BlobHttpHeaders().setContentType("image/jpeg"));
    
// Upload the blob
blobClient.uploadFromFile(myJpgLocalPath + myJpgFile, false);
```

None of these two works at all and fails even building the client.

The errors shown are these two:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.PackageVersion
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1412)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1220)
        at com.azure.core.implementation.jackson.JacksonVersion.<init>(JacksonVersion.java:46)
        at com.azure.core.implementation.jackson.JacksonVersion.getInstance(JacksonVersion.java:72)
        at com.azure.core.implementation.jackson.ObjectMapperShim.<clinit>(ObjectMapperShim.java:40)
        at com.azure.core.util.serializer.JacksonAdapter.<init>(JacksonAdapter.java:81)
        at com.azure.core.util.serializer.JacksonAdapter.<init>(JacksonAdapter.java:59)
        at com.azure.core.util.serializer.JacksonAdapter$SerializerAdapterHolder.<clinit>(JacksonAdapter.java:114)
        at com.azure.core.util.serializer.JacksonAdapter.createDefaultSerializerAdapter(JacksonAdapter.java:123)
        at com.azure.storage.blob.implementation.util.ModelHelper.<clinit>(ModelHelper.java:62)
        at com.azure.storage.blob.BlobUrlParts.parse(BlobUrlParts.java:371)
        at com.azure.storage.blob.BlobContainerClientBuilder.endpoint(BlobContainerClientBuilder.java:181)
...

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.azure.storage.blob.implementation.util.ModelHelper
        at com.azure.storage.blob.BlobUrlParts.parse(BlobUrlParts.java:371)
        at com.azure.storage.blob.BlobContainerClientBuilder.endpoint(BlobContainerClientBuilder.java:181)
...
```

What I am doing bad?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: post edited with the errors

Comment: Can you share the value of your `ENDPOINT`variable? Replace the account name with something else if you like to.

Comment: Sure. I wrote it on the top of the code

Answer (score 0):

The Azure Storage Blob SDK is attempting to determine the version of Jackson Dataformat XML and it's unable to find the PackageVersion class in jackson-dataformat-xml. This is indicating a few possible issues, Jackson Dataformat XML isn't part of the application or the Azure Storage Blob SDK doesn't have access to PackageVersion.

Aside from that the code you've written for uploading the blob should work.